# Puzzled by breaker trip

Tags: dimmer-switch, smart-switch

Installing a Wemo (switch 1) to replace a 2-pole switch that controls a single outdoor light, which is on the same breaker as the other switch and dimmer in this box.

I made connections as illustrated in the photo, with the Wemo neutral connected to the other neutrals in the box.

The Wemo powered up and connected with the app, but when I flipped switch 2, it tripped the breaker (you can see the black char on the red connector).

I checked for shorts, but found none.

Between this description and the photo, is there enough information to determine what caused the breaker to trip?

[image]

Comment: Easiest possibility is one of the bare grounds was touching a switch hot screw when you stuff everything back into the box.  Some wrap tape around switches for this reason.

Comment: Obligatory questions... Did it all work before you started, and did you do anything to the wires on the switch 2 or the dimmer?

Comment: What, _exactly_ did you change in the wiring? A super-common reason for this is that you have "fixed" an "incorrect" white (that was a hot wire in a switch loop) into the neutral bundle. Flip the switch, dead short. If you respect the (working) wiring you find and transfer wires appropriately, that's less likely. From the single picture it's hard to say, as we don't know where this started.

Comment: The only change I made was to replace a single pole switch with the WEMO. Nothing else was changed. I checked carefully and didn’t see any short possibilities, but will try wrapping with electrical tape to rule it out.

Comment: Why is the Semo neutral not connected?

Comment: I'd temporarily disconnected it after the short. Update: I carefully reviewed every wire and connection, reconnected the Wemo, and wrapped Switch 2 with electrical tape to prevent any shorts when re-packing the box. Despite my initial checking, that must've been the culprit, as everything works flawlessly now. Thanks everyone for the input!